# laravel how to call a method when a row inserted in model?

Tags: laravel, mutators

I have two model (`Cart` & `AcceptedCart`) and I want to run this method when a row insrted in `AcceptedCart` model :

```
    public function dataUpdated()
    {
      $cart = Cart::where('id' , $this->cart_id)->first();
      $sum = 0;
      $acceptedCarts = AcceptedCart::where('cart_id' , $this->cart_id)->get();
      foreach($acceptedCarts as $acceptedCart){
          $sum += $acceptedCart->accepted_count;
      }
      if ($sum == $cart->product_quantity){
          $cart->full_accepted = true;
          $cart->save();
      }
    }
```

as you see, I change `full_accpted = true` in the `cart` model.

the AcceptedCart migration is :

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('accepted_carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('cart_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('accepted_by')->nullable();
        $table->integer('accepted_count');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('cart_id')->references('id')->on('carts');
    });
}
```

and Cart migration is :

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->boolean('full_accepted')->default(false);
        $table->text('address');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

how can I call this `dataUpdated` method every time a row inserted to `AcceptedCart` model?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the models `booted()` method to achieve this simple task, also you can use the separate observer class to listen to model events like created/updated/deleted, etc.

E.g. 1. How you can listen to model events in the same model.

```php
class AcceptedCart extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::created(function ($acceptedCart) {
           $acceptedCart->dataUpdated();
        });
        // Similarly you can do for updated/deleted events as well
    }
}
```

E.g. 2. You can use Observer class to listen to events

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Observers;
 
use App\Models\AcceptedCart;
 
class AcceptedCartObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the AcceptedCart "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\AcceptedCart  $acceptedCart
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(AcceptedCart $acceptedCart)
    {
        $acceptedCart->dataUpdated();
    }
 
    /**
     * Handle the AcceptedCart "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\AcceptedCart  $acceptedCart
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(AcceptedCart $acceptedCart)
    {
        // Similarly for update
    }
}
```

You can learn more here about [Model Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#observers)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using Observers.

Events can be fired when a Model is created/updated and so on.

You can find out more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers).